# Changing the colours of menu-bar pop-ups (not of the menu-bar itself)

Tags: colors, menu-bar, popup, menus

[Crossposting from `gnu.emacs.help` after getting no response there.]

With Emacs 27.1, in the terminal the standard colour scheme, the pop-ups of the menu I get via F10 have a blue background and with the foreground for menu items being either white(-ish) or browny-orange.  The highlighting background colour for selection is red, which for makes the browny-orange illegible.

My question is: How do I change the colour of the pop-ups?

The following changes the menu-bar itself, but not the pop-ups:

```
    (set-face-attribute 'menu nil
                        :inverse-video nil
                        :background "blue"
                        :foreground "white"
                        :bold t)
```

Comment: It goes through `menu-bar-open->popup-menu->x-popup-menu (C code) -> x_popup_menu_1` but then I lost track: I don't know how the colors are assigned. OTOH, things are perfectly legible for me: wheat against either a blue background or a red background. Not sure why you get brown-orange.

Comment: Following @dalanicolai's answer, when I use ```emacs -nw -q```, customize claims that the foreground for ```tty-menu-enabled``` is ```yellow```, but it looks pretty grubby to me.

Comment: Only one question per post, please. Please edit to remove all but one of your questions here. Post the others separately. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x list-faces-display` can be used to list all faces. Then, by quickly scrolling through all faces and looking for faces that resemble the 'menu-bar pop-up face', it can be quickly found that the names of the faces used for the menu-bar pop-up start with `tty-menu-...`. Now, simply use `M-x customize-face` `tty-menu-enabled/disabled/selected` to configure the popup faces.

Answer (score 0):

I have subsequently realised that the settings of my Gnome terminal were influencing the colours of the Emacs menu. For the setting `Preferences / Colours / Palette / Built-in schemes` I had `Solarized`, which lead to the rather hard to read grubby yellow on lightish blue.  Changing this setting to `Gnome` or `Xterm` results in a more legible scheme.